# C - in recursive function remove() dont work

Tags: c, linux

obviating if the recursive function is well constructed or not, when i call the function on a directory Folder/file.txt. this code should delete file.txt, but when it reaches to

```
if (remove(actual->d_name) != 0 && rmdir(actual->d_name) != 0){
```

remove dont work, and i dont know for what...

```
 void borrarrecursivo(DIR *directorio){

      struct dirent *actual;

          while(((actual = readdir(directorio)) != NULL) && (actual->d_name) != NULL){
            if ((strcmp(actual->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(actual->d_name, "..") != 0)){
              if (remove(actual->d_name) != 0 && rmdir(actual->d_name) != 0){
                  DIR *siguiente;
                  if ((siguiente = opendir(actual->d_name)) != NULL){
                    borrarrecursivo(siguiente);
                  }
              }
            }
          }
          closedir(directorio);
      //}
    }//fin borrarrecursivo
```

Comment: you want to remove from the current directory or the previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the man page on `readdir`, it returns in `d_name` a *file* name, not a complete path, but `remove` and `rmdir` expect a full path (or an entry relative to current working directory).

So with every recursive call of your function, you must construct a new path of where you currently are, and pass that in your recursive call. (I leave to you to change your code to achieve this.)

Note: you also assume that if you can neither remove, nor rmdir, it must be a directory and you want to recurse. But it does not have to be a directory. You should check the `d_type` field.

Note: the man page for remove says it calls rmdir if the name is a directory. Calling rmdir is thus unnecessary.